# How can I identify the name of the input of a file field?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have two file upload fields.  The files are uploaded fine, but I need to store their names to two separate database tables.  How do I identify which file comes from which field.

Example,

One file is a CV - must be stored in DB field "user_cv"
The other is a video - must be stored in DB field "user_video"

How can I make sure that the correct filename is stored to the correct field?

Is there an extra data atrribute or something that I can send along with the $_FILES array?

Comment: **R.T.M** [Handling file uploads](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) If you have 2 files uploaded the `$_FILES['uploads']` should be an array containing 2 occurances one for each file.

Comment: @RiggsFolly :  That still does not help me with storing the appropriate file name in the appropriate field.  I am using wordpress, so it returns a  generated ID, and I have no way of matching the id to the appropriate DB field.

Comment: Oh right, so you need to [R.T.WP.M](https://codex.wordpress.org/) and probably the manual for whatever plugin you are using. At least you could have put the WordPress tag on the question. What plugin are you using?

Comment: @RiggsFolly  Sorry mate, I am being an idiot.  I was looping over the files array and obviously did not see the $_FILES['field_id'], just the contents of the array.